# how to Remove nbsp element from an array

Tags: php, arrays, encoding

i have elements in my php array who contain &nbsp elements , i try to remove the elements who contain only space (&nbsp), so i apply on my array:

```
        $steps = array_map( 'html_entity_decode', $steps);
        $steps = array_map('trim',$steps);
        $steps = array_filter($steps, 'strlen'); //(i try also array_filter($steps);
```

but the elements reside.

Any idea please

Comment: What data are you trying to parse? Give us an example

Comment: sure:
<p>step1</p>
<p>step2</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>step3</p>

array(1 => step1, 2=> step2 , 3=> , 4=> , step3);

Comment: sure: 
i scrape from html page this block and i put him in an array , so i got this output :
<p>step1</p>
<p>step2</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>step3</p>
print_r($steps) :
array(1 => step1, 2=> step2 , 3=> , 4=> , step3);

Comment: I think your problem is that you're using html_entity_decode() instead of strip_tags(). I updated my code below to reflect that.

Comment: You can use `string_replace()` - https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Comment: @Mr.Turtle, did you mean `str_replace()`? :-)

Comment: Yes, of course. `str_replace()` is correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Function to strip away a given string
 **/
function remove_nbsp($string){
    $string_to_remove = "&nbsp;";
    return str_replace($string_to_remove, "", $string);
}

# Example data array
$steps = array("<p>step1</p>", "<p>step2</p>", "<p>step3</p>", "<p>&nbsp;</p>", "&nbsp;", "<p>&nbsp;</p>",  "<p>step4</p>");

$steps = array_map("strip_tags", $steps);
//Strip_tags() will remove the HTML tags
$steps = array_map("remove_nbsp", $steps);
//Our custom function will remove the &nbsp; character
$steps = array_filter($steps);
//Array_filter() will remove any blank array values

var_dump($steps);

/**
 * Output:
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "step1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "step2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "step3"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "step4"
}
*/
```

You might even find it easier to do a foreach():

```
foreach($steps as $dirty_step){
    if(!$clean_step = trim(str_replace("&nbsp;", "", strip_tags($dirty_step)))){
        //Ignore empty steps
        continue;
    }
    $clean_steps[] = $clean_step;
}
```